# how to check high read or write usage on table in sybase 16

Tags: sybase

I want which table have most read or write process in Sybase 16 in linux

I want which table have most read or write process in Sybase 16 in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're working with the Sybase `ASE` product you might want to start with the MDA table [(master..)monOpenObjectActivity](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/ad4a1ddf1bf34768841bd09d1eddf434/aba20430bc2b1014a568a4cb74ec9ef2.html) which maintains several counters including logical/physical (page) reads, number of rows inserted/updated/deleted, etc.

For more details on setting up, configuring and using MDA tables see the [Performance & Tuning Series: Monitoring Tables](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/9a57ec3c9937415eb6bf8c5abc91ca86/a6615a93bc2b1014b21ac28b99447402.html) manual.